# BarMark Chart going off scale on xAxis

Tags: swiftui, charts

I'm trying to display Date and Scores for the last six months on a bar chart.  When setting the .chartXScale(domain:) for the start month and ending month my bars go off scale.  If I remove the modifier it works but then I loose control over setting the scale when the data changes to the previous 6 months range.

```
@State var currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
@State var currentMonth = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date())
var quizTrackingSorted: [QuizTrackingSort]

 var endingMonth: Date {
        let currentMonthYear = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: currentYear, month: currentMonth)) ?? Date()
        return Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .month, for: currentMonthYear)?.start ?? Date()
    }
    
var beginningMonth: Date {
        let currentMonthYear = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year:    currentYear, month: currentMonth))!
        let month = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -6, to: currentMonthYear) ?? Date()
        return Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .month, for: month)!.end
    }

Chart {
      ForEach(calculateAverageScorePerMonth(currentYear, currentMonth), id: \.date) { quiz in
         BarMark(
              x: .value("date", quiz.date, unit: .month),
              y: .value("score", Int(quiz.score)))
            .annotation(position: .top, alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                 Text("\(Int(quiz.score.rounded()))")
                       .font(.caption)
                       .foregroundColor(.gray)
             }
             .clipShape(RoundedCorner(radius: 8, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight]))
             .foregroundStyle(quiz.score > 79 ? .green : .red)
          }
          .frame(height: 250)
          .chartXScale(domain: beginningMonth...endingMonth) // <-- HERE



func calculateAverageScorePerMonth(_ year: Int, _ month: Int) -> [QuizTrackingSort] {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM-yyyy"
        
        let date = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month))!
        
        let last6MonthsQuizTracking = quizTrackingSorted.filter { $0.date >= Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -6, to: date) ?? Date()  }
        
        let groupedQuizTrackings = Dictionary(grouping: last6MonthsQuizTracking) { quizTracking in
            let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: quizTracking.date)
            return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
            
        }

        var averageScoresForMonths: [QuizTrackingSort] = []
        
        for (month, quizTrackingsForMonth) in groupedQuizTrackings {
            let totalScoreForMonth = quizTrackingsForMonth.reduce(0) { $0 + Double($1.score) }
            let averageScoreForMonth = totalScoreForMonth / Double(quizTrackingsForMonth.count)
            let results = QuizTrackingSort(date: month, score: averageScoreForMonth)
            averageScoresForMonths.append(results)
        }
        
        return averageScoresForMonths
    }
```

[image: Chart]

Tried modifying the beginningMonth and endingMonth date properties with continued result.  Tried removing the modifier but I loose control over the dates selected. QuizTrackingSort is model of date: Date and score: CGFloat properties